# Problem with reading 433MHz RF receiver

Tags: gpio, serial, rpi.gpio

I have problem with reading 433MHz signal. Not receiving it!
I want to read it or clone it to send it with my sender hardware.
My whole idea is to clone signals sent by my radio remote of windows blinds and send it from phone using home automation.

I am a software guy, not much of a hardware guy.

There are many examples on the internet of how to connect and use these cheap RF senders and receivers. For example:
https://www.instructables.com/RF-433-MHZ-Raspberry-Pi/

I've looked through and tried all of them, and now I am out of ideas.

All the programs written in python and cpp cannot read the signal I am trying to sniff.

I know I am receiving it. I installed piscope and when pressing buttons on my radio remote I can see the signal.

Here are screenshot of the signal I am receiving, so I know my hardware is working.

I also tried to clone this signal and resend it with Domoticz software, but I cannot get it to work either.

Can someone help me how do it? What should I change in any of the example programs on the internet? Is there some easy way to map piscope files/data(of saved signal) into some usable format I would be able to send with 433 RF sender?

[image: Here is the signal I am receiving in piscope]
[image: Tried making one part of signal bigger]
[image: One part of signal wider]

Answer (score 1):

Same here. Receiver works, tested with an LED and raw reading of the GPIO input, though rpi-rf script does not seem to proces it. Could it be that rpi-rf does not recognize the rf coding?